# Conditions used in joining two tables

Tags: mysql, left-join, conditional-statements

I am using following query, but not getting exact result. In this query I used two conditions, first one is common value in both tables ie students, fees. Second one is checking a match with the variable "cid"

```
SELECT *, students.student_id as studid, sum(fees_amount) as total_paid
FROM students
LEFT JOIN fees ON fees.class_id='$_GET[cid]' AND students.student_id=fees.student_id
GROUP By students.student_id ORDER by student_name
```

Is there any wrong in using such two conditions. ( I think there is  no need of table details for answering)

Comment: That's the right way to do it with an `OUTER JOIN`. It would be a mistake to move the condition that checks a value in the left joined table `fees` to the `WHERE` clause, because it would change the `LEFT JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: You've got a special problem with your query: all values in columns from the fees table in your resultset are nondeterministic, the only exception is your `sum(fees_amount) as total_paid`, I cite from the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-extensions.html): **The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate.** Is that your problem?

Comment: Does this altered code work? `SELECT *, students.student_id as studid, sum(fees_amount) as total_paid FROM students 
     LEFT JOIN fees ON  students.student_id=fees.student_id
     WHERE fees.class_id='$_GET[cid]' GROUP By students.student_id ORDER by student_name`

Comment: All columns from the students table should be the same for the same `studend_id`. If you're getting other data than you expect, I assume it must be data in columns from the `fees` table.

Comment: You should add a minimum example (two tables with the minimum of columns) and the result that you want. That would make help easier for anyone.

Comment: As I posted in above comment, I just changed second join condition to "WHERE" Clause. Now it give the result that I expect. `SELECT *, students.student_id as studid, sum(fees_amount) as total_paid FROM students       LEFT JOIN fees ON  students.student_id=fees.student_id      WHERE fees.class_id='$_GET[cid]' GROUP By students.student_id ORDER by student_name` Now its OK.

Comment: Then you can change your `LEFT JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: I used left join because some student_id in students table have no corresponding rows in fees table. But I need all student_id from students table even it dont have any rows in fees table. So Am I right with the code I pasted in comment. Please help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56814/discussion-between-vmai-and-user1010966).

Answer (score 0):

yes your query and condition will work absolutely fine but the problem might be with the $_GET.

1) First check the $_GET['cid'] is set or not that means to check whether the index exists

2) try storing it in another variable like $value=$_GET["cid"];

3) if that still doesnt work you will want to replace it with the filter_input and the input_post

```
     $valuee=filter_input(INPUT_POST,"cid")
```

and then do the fee.class_id='$valuee'